# Touch Bar display partly not working

Tags: macbook-pro, display, mojave, touch-bar

My Mac's Touch Bar's display doesn't work near the Touch ID button, and I have no idea why. There is supposed to be a Siri button at that location, but it's not there.

The touch still works at the black area, but I hope the display isn't broken or something.

Tried Restarting and resetting the SMC, but it didn't work.

Device: MBP 2018 13-inch Touch Bar
OS: macOS Mojave 10.14.6

When I screenshot the Touch Bar, the Siri button is in it:
[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't really know anything about the touchbar, but I think you might want to add your macOS version in the question.

Comment: When you say *"The touch still works at the black area"*, what does that mean? Do you mean you're able to use the *missing* Siri button? Or do you mean something else? Also, have you tested to see if you can get anything else to appear in that space (i.e. by customising your Touch Bar)?

Comment: @Monomeeth Yes, I can still use the Siri button, but there's just no graphics displayed there. I've tried to make that part display something by these methods: Control Strip Expansion, Opening Emoji Selector, Opening Color Picker. None of these work.

Comment: @Joonas I edited the question to include the version

Comment: Try making a new user.

Comment: This same exact thing is happening to me as well, it's as if the touchbar just got cut off there or the LCD went dead without accident etc..

Comment: @knishka Some update, I eventually had to go to the Apple store to get it fixed. It was an issue with the LCD itself I believe because they replaced the LCD for me

Comment: @knishka But, if your MacBook is out of warranty, try taking it to the Apple Store, because you never know what they will say. Thanks to a very nice technician at the genius bar, I got it replaced for free! I am still very thankful to that guy...

Comment: @knishka Hope it helps

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. First only 4 cm on the right side. As of today, more than half of the touch bar isn't displaying anything, though it does still respond to touch.

Comment: Same problem here

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple processes that send data back and forth and this is a sign you need you log out of the user account so that those processes can exit and then when you log in, see if the connection is fixed.

Unless this is something that you run into very often, I'd log out and then restart to be sure it's not systemic before expending a lot if time digging into this.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the 2 Inch length of the right-hand part of the touchbar stopped displaying, but the touch was working from **Mar 05, 2020.**

Fortunately, on **Oct 03, 2020** it miraculously reappeared. Now, only half-a cm of the touchbar is still black. I hope it also comes back soon.
[image]